# Drop a 3D character into the void

Tags: swift, scenekit

I try to make my character "fall" to the next level on the floor. I tried to do it with physicsBody. When I do it with a box it works great but when I try with a 3D model it doesn't work at all. It moves weirdly in all directions instead of falling in a straight line...

Do you know how to do it correctly?

Here is my code.

```
let cameraNode = SCNNode()
cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 1, 15)
cameraNode.eulerAngles.x = 50
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        
let floor = SCNFloor()
floor.reflectionFalloffEnd = 0
floor.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red        
let floorNode = SCNNode(geometry: floor)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(floorNode)
         
let modelScene = SCNScene(named: "Art.scnassets/max.scn")!
let modelNode = modelScene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "Max_rootNode", 
                                           recursively: true)!
modelNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 5, 0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(modelNode)
         
modelNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .dynamic, shape: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

try to study how Apple does move a character as presented on WWDC 2016. The **Fox** example app. They use a kinematic `physicsBody`, which is controlled by the `updateAtTime` function entirely.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016154

*(**Character.swift**, the **walkInDirection()** function - also handles a fall)*

PS: A dynamic `physicsBody` cannot be controlled directly in a proper way. It is designed to be moved by the physics engine only.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the response.

I looked at Apple's code but I can't quite understand how they make fox go down and he stops on the ground...

Moreover I have the impression that they do not use physicsBody but that they code gravity by hand on fox... I would have liked to know if we could use physicsBody to do this automatically...

Comment: well, you could give your model a dynamic physicsBody using the geometry of i.ex. a SCNBox. Put the restitution to 0.0 and let the object fall on the ground. If you want to have a character, that is controlable within the scene, you should consider to study the Apple Fox App. It' is really a good piece of work.

Comment: PS: what does your character represent? A human body? An animal? A sphere? Some other geometry? Do you scale your object? This all depends on how the physics engine can affect the object.

Comment: a humain body. But  for the moment I took the apple fox to do some tests :)

Comment: I tried with the box... it falls but the 3D model stays on top... lol

Comment: Might be an issue with the pivot position of the box you add as physics body. I consider to go the Apple/Fox way.